# Matplotlib memory leak

Tags: matplotlib, memory-leaks

I have a loop that turns financial OHLC price data into rgb pixel data. The process is:

1, Get the OHLC price data

2, draw the OHLC data into images with Matplotlib finance

3, Get the rgb pixel data from fig.canvas

For this program, I am drawing 50 price data into one chart, and stacking four incremental chart into one, so I am getting (120*120*4) per pixel data. Since this will result in opening and closing thousands of matplotlib subplots, I am having significant memory leak.

I have tried basically all methods to deal with this leak, including:

1, plt.close('all'),

2, del fig, ax

3, using fig = figure.Figure(), instead of fig,ax = plt.subplots()

I also tried changing the matplotlib backend from Qt4agg to agg, but the leak still exists. I even tried multiprocessing the process, but still won't solve the problem.

The code are here:

```
    def get_data(file_dir):
      data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(file_dir)
      return data

    file_dir = 'C:/Users/czzis/Desktop/DATA/EURUSD_ALL/DAT_MT_EURUSD_M1_2016.CSV' 
    data = get_data(file_dir)

    b = []
    start = 0
    idx = 50
    stack = 4

    for i in range(22370):   

        a = np.zeros(shape = (120,120,1))

        for i in range(stack):

            opens = data.iloc[start+i : idx+i ,1].as_matrix()
            highs = data.iloc[start+i : idx+i ,2].as_matrix()
            lows = data.iloc[start+i : idx+i ,3].as_matrix()
            closes = data.iloc[start+i : idx+i ,4].as_matrix()

            # We would draw the chart first and then get the rgb data 
    #       fig = figure.Figure()
    #       ax = fig.add_axes([1, 1, 1, 1])
    #       ax.set_axis_off()

            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            plt.axis('off')
            matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax, opens, highs, lows, closes, width=0.6, colorup='w', colordown='k', alpha=1)
    #       print(i)
    #       del fig
    #       canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

    #       fig.set_canvas(canvas) 
            fig.canvas.draw()   
            observation = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
            observation = observation.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))       

            # Process Data
            observation = skimage.transform.resize(observation,(120,120))  
            observation = np.delete(observation,np.s_[1:4], axis = 2)  
            observation = np.reshape(observation,(120,120,1))   # a is the final shrinked image data we need 

            a = np.append(a,observation,axis = 2)  

    #       matplotlib.pyplot.close('all')
    #       plt.clf()
            plt.show()
            plt.close('all')
    #       del fig,ax
    #       plt.close("all")
    #       del fig,ax
    #       print()
    #       del fig.canvas

        observation = np.delete(a,np.s_[0:1],axis = 2)
        start += 1
        idx   += 1

        b.append(observation)
```

None of the method can fix this leak. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: To add on this, I have tried gc.collect() in the loop as well, but it won't clear the memory too.

Comment: I have the same problem...:(

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but had the same issue when creating and saving figures recently.
Tried all the same things you did, without success.

In the end, adding the below line to turn off interactive mode in Matplpotlib before starting into my loop did the trick.
The memory stays reasonable for me when running through +5000 subplots.

```
plt.ioff()
```